# In Windows Server, how to find out which user changed another user's password?

Tags: windows, windows-server

I'm having a strange issue on a production Windows server where an OS service account's password was unexpectedly changed. Since the service account is used by all business users (it's a client-server application), it caused widespread issues for all business users. In order to restore service we had to change the password back to what we know it should be.

How can I set up monitoring on this event so the server team gets notified immediately after the user's password is changed? It's best if the same monitoring mechanism can report which user changed the account's password.

The user being changed is a server user. It is not an Active Directory user. I do not think this architecture will change because it is used by a legacy program. Very difficult to change.

Thank you for helping me out!

Comment: No time for a real answer here, but try events 4273 and 4274. They should hold the information you seek.

Answer (score 1):

Even not a domain-joinned machine, we can audit the account changes.
We can configure it through gpedit. msc.

Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\Audit Policy\account management
For more details ,you can refer to:
https://blogs.manageengine.com/active-directory/2018/08/23/monitoring-service-account-password-changes-active-directory.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem in my case is not that the machine is not domain-joined. The machine actually is, causing my not being able to follow your advice because that part of local group policy is locked and I could not change it. The problem in my case is that the user is not a domain user.